# tar multiple files starting with same pattern then spaces in between the file name

Tags: tar, solaris

I am trying tar files from a directory which has files starting with same pattern then multiple spaces in between. e.g.:

```
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:02:00 2023 log.TXT.0
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:05:00 2023 log.TXT.0
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:06:00 2023 log.TXT.0
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:07:00 2023 log.TXT.0
```

The tar file, named TXT_log_09032023.tar, takes only one of those files, remaining are omitted or overwritten.

Already tried quoting the file name, IFS=$'\n', IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") etc.

I am using `find` to find files older than 3 days and `-exec tar uf` to update the tar file. In this way, it's only taking first file. Before that, `touch` the tar file to update it subsequently.

Comment: I don't see how this could go wrong. And it's also not clear where you need to set IFS. Please show us the actual command you are executing to create that tar. We can't debug what we can't see!

Comment: `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")`
`DT=$(date +%d%m%Y)`
`touch TXT_Logs_${DT}.tar`
`find . -name "*TXT*" -mtime +3 -exec tar uf TXT_Logs_${DT}.tar {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple as:

```
$ ls -1
'ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:02:00 2023 log.TXT.0'
'ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:05:00 2023 log.TXT.0'
'ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:06:00 2023 log.TXT.0'
'ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:07:00 2023 log.TXT.0'

$ tar cf /tmp/tar.tar *

$ tar tf /tmp/tar.tar
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:02:00 2023 log.TXT.0
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:05:00 2023 log.TXT.0
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:06:00 2023 log.TXT.0
ABCDEFGH Mar 09 20:07:00 2023 log.TXT.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question with more details.
`tar uf` is making my day tough.